# How can I insert a column of a dataframe in pandas as a list of a cell into another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have several of dataframes (df, tmp_df and sub_df) and I want to enter a column of tmp_df into a cell of sub_df as a list. My code and dataframes are shown as below. But the loop part is not working correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame()
sub_df = pd.DataFrame()
tmp_df = df[df['Type'] == True]
for c in tmp_df['Category']:
    sub_df['Data'] , sub_df ['Category'], sub_df['Type'] = [list(set(tmp_df['Data']))],
    tmp_df['Category'], tmp_df['Type']
```

df:

| Data | Category | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30275 | A | True |
| 35881 | C | False |
| 28129 | C | True |
| 30274 | D | False |
| 30351 | D | True |
| 35886 | A | True |
| 39900 | C | True |
| 35887 | A | False |
| 35883 | A | True |
| 35856 | D | True |
| 35986 | C | False |
| 30350 | D | False |
| 28129 | C | True |
| 31571 | C | True |

tmp_df:

| Data | Category | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30275 | A | True |
| 28129 | C | True |
| 30351 | D | True |
| 35886 | A | True |
| 39900 | C | True |
| 35883 | A | True |
| 35856 | D | True |
| 28129 | C | True |
| 31571 | C | True |

What should I do if I want the following result?

sub_df:

| Data | Category | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [30275,35886,35883] | A | True |
| [28129,39900,28129,31571] | C | True |
| [30351,35856] | D | True |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select the rows with`query`, then `groupby`+`agg`:

```
(df.query('Type') # or 'Type == "True"' if strings
   .groupby('Category', as_index=False)
   .agg({'Data': list, 'Type': 'first'})
)
```

output:

```
  Category                          Data  Type
0        A         [30275, 35886, 35883]  True
1        C  [28129, 39900, 28129, 31571]  True
2        D                [30351, 35856]  True
```